# accessing all the property bindings at once in an angular component

Tags: angular, components

I have a component which has a property binding name like `<app-ang-acb [name]="nameVal"></app-ang-acb>` I want to access it in `component.ts` file without using `@Input() name`.

Any leads please, tried using ComponentFactory, but no luck.

Comment: May I ask why would you?

Comment: I actually need to use to render web components which uses getter/setter way of attr/prop binding, basically I want angular attr/prop to b in sync with web component

Comment: Well, you can access such property value using `ElementRef` and `ViewChid` for example, however I've no working experience with web components, so maybe I'm not helping, hopefully someone experienced answers this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Input and Output together with getter/setter way

```
  <app-ang-acb [(name)]="nameVal"></app-ang-acb>
```

parent.component.ts

```
  nameValue = 0;
  @Input()
  get name() {
    return this.nameValue;
  }

  @Output() nameChange = new EventEmitter();

  set name(val) {
    this.nameVal = val;
    this.nameChange.emit(this.nameVal);
  }
```